# jQuery replace part of a String

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace part of a string that contains specific text, I can't figure out what I'm missing. Can someone shed some light?

```
function trimUser() {
    var trimString = $('#selectedUsername').text();
    var trimmedString = "";
    trimmedString = $(trimString).text().replace(' - SupportUser', '');
    $(this).text(trimmedString);
    console.log(trimmedString);
}
```

Comment: Change `trimmedString = $(trimString).text().replace(' - SupportUser', '');` to `trimmedString = trimString.replace(' - SupportUser', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i guess maybe your `trimmedString = $(trimString).text().replace(' - SupportUser', '');` is mistake, you dont have element call `$(trimString)`

```
function trimUser() {
    var myelement = $('#selectedUsername');
    var trimString = myelement.text();
    var trimmedString = "";
    trimmedString = trimString.replace(' - SupportUser', '');
    myelement.text(trimmedString);
    console.log(trimmedString);
}
```